# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am learning java using a book. There is this exercise that I can't get to work properly. It adds two doubles using the java class Double. When I try to run this code in Eclipse it gives me the error in the title.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double d1 = Double.valueOf(args[0]);
    Double d2 = Double.valueOf(args[1]);
    double result = d1.doubleValue() + d2.doubleValue();
    System.out.println(args[0] + "+" + args[1] + "=" + result);

}
```

Comment: Are you passing command line arguments ie value for `args[0]` and `args[1]`?

Comment: Read [Eclipse : how we take arguments for main when run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222153/eclipse-how-we-take-arguments-for-main-when-run)

Comment: For any "real" Java application (not a testcase or toy) you should check args.length before you access individual args values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Problem

This `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` means that the index `0` is not a valid index for your array `args[]`, which in turn means that your array is empty.

In this particular case of a `main()` method, it means that **no argument was passed** on to your program on the command line.

### Possible solutions

- If you're running your program from the command line, don't forget to pass 2 arguments in the command (2, because you're accessing `args[0]` and `args[1]`)
- If you're running your program in Eclipse, you should set the command line arguments in the run configuration. Go to `Run > Run configurations...` and then choose the `Arguments` tab for your run configuration and add some arguments in the *program arguments* area.

Note that **you should handle the case where not enough arguments are given**, with something like this at the beginning of your main method:

```
if (args.length < 2) {
    System.err.println("Not enough arguments received.");
    return;
}
```

This would fail gracefully instead of making your program crash.

Answer (score 3):

This code expects to get two arguments when it's run (the `args` array).
The fact that accessing `args[0]` causes a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you aren't passing any.